# Error when pickling dynamically defined extension of an abstract base class

Tags: python, dynamic, pickle

I would like to persist an object that is created from a dynamically defined class that extends an abstract base class. I have tried to achieve this by pickling the object. I am using Python 3.6.8

The error message suggests that pickle is trying to look for the class I have created within the abc module and is unable to find it there. I have tried to pickle by creating the class within the main module (by defining class_factory inside test.py) but I get the same error message.

objmodel.py

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class mtype(ABC):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @abstractmethod
    def set_someattrib(self, attrval):
        pass


@classmethod
def set_attrib1(cls, aval):
    cls.attrib = aval
```

utils.py

```
from objmodel import *


def class_factory(mname, aval):
    c1 = type(mname, (mtype,), {"set_someattrib": set_attrib1})
    c1.set_someattrib(aval)
    return c1
```

test.py

```
from utils import class_factory
import pickle

c1 = class_factory('C', 1)
print(c1.attrib)
m = c1()
fh = open('objtest', 'wb')
pickle.dump(m, fh)
```

I get the following error:
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle : attribute lookup C on abc failed